# Script runs on 50 servers. How can I ensure only one executes a particular step?

Tags: bash, shell

I have some work that needs to be done on 50+ servers. The first step is to checkout an updated version of some source code onto a shared directory (assume all have the shared drive mounted). The second is to perform some work on each of the servers.

I'd prefer to have these two scripts run on each of the servers. All 50+ servers are cloned from a single disk image and it's not practical for me to customize any of them.

When the 50 servers run the first script, I want only the first one that tries to run it to actually run it. The others I want to simply exit. The server that actually runs the script should then update a shared directory, then exit. Then, later, the second script will run and perform the work on all servers based on the updated code that the first server fetched.

What's the best way to do this? Can I reliable have the first script run on one server and create a file or something that acts as a 'semaphore' or 'lock' of some sort that keeps the other servers away?

Making this more complicated is that I'm thinking of having the scripts run from identical cron files on each of the servers -- meaning all scripts could try to run it at the same time assuming all their clocks are set identically.

I'm hoping these will be run from bash scripts. Does this make sense as an approach?

Comment: Great question for serverfault.com.

Comment: Do you want them to run in a specific order?

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth It does not matter which order the 50+ servers run the second script. They will run it on their own file systems and won't interfere with each other.

Comment: @nosid Can you craft an example as an answer so I can consider it as the answer?

Answer (score 2):

In most environments, creating a directory is an atomic operation and can be used as a lock.

Assuming you have /mnt/common mounted on all servers, you could use a function like this in your script #1:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/common/script_1.lock || exit 1
... do your work ...
rmdir /mnt/common/script_1.lock
```

This is only the simple case; you may need to store your PID somewhere, and you need to handle kills/crashes of the script which leave the lock laying around (e.g. by checking if the PID that you stored earlier is still running, and if not, remove the lock).

More information about this kind of locks can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#Lock_files).

**Edit**:
Another type of atomic lock could be obtained by using SQL atomic operations (which can be executed from within a script, since most SQL implementations provide a command line client).

Comment: upvote for pointing out that mkdir is atomic. Only issue with PID files is that the lock dir will have to be on an nfs shared drive and the file may have been created by a rmote server -- meaning the PIC won't exist locally. Also, is mkdir atomic even across an NFS mount?

Comment: @KevinBedell From what I remember it depends on the implementation/NFS version, so don't take for granted it's atomic with NFS (someone please provide a proper source for my allegation).

Comment: The NFS RFC (http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1094.html) only specifies "Write to File" and "Rename File" as atomic operations. However, even so it's not possible to tell *which* client was successful with the rename operation, when more than one client tries to rename file "A" to "B" (under certain conditions, NFS may report success to more than one client).

@KevinBedell: good point about the remote PID.